# Term for the number ω in a quadratic number field?

Tags: terminology, algebraic-number-theory

Associated to the quadratic field $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$ (for $D$ square-free) is a number, denoted $\omega$ in all the discussions I’ve seen, defined by
$$\omega =
\begin{cases}
\frac{-1 + \sqrt{D}}{2} & \text{if}\ D \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \\
\sqrt{D} & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

(It’s used, for instance, in the standard description of the [algebraic integers of K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) as $\mathbb{Z} + \omega \mathbb{Z}$.)

**Is there a standard term for this number, other than just $\omega$?**

Comment: I don’t think that that notation is all that standard. For me (and maybe for me only) $\omega$ is that constant when $D=-3$.

Comment: @Lubin: In e.g. a complex-analysis context, I’d quite agree that $\omega$ conventionally means $(\sqrt{3}i - 1)/2$.  In algebraic number theory, though, this seems quite common — I’m very unfamiliar with the field, but the first few sources I met it in all used $\omega$ for this: [Jozsa’s *Notes on Hallgren’s algotithm*](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0302134), [these notes of Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/quadraticundergrad.pdf), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this post, almost $10$ years too late.  Since a comment by the OP includes a link to something I wrote, let me first point out that when $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, I did *not* use $\omega$ at the link to mean $(-1 + \sqrt{D})/2$: I wrote $\omega$ for $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$, and it is $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$, *not* $(-1+\sqrt{D})/2$, that is used universally in the case $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. The Wikipedia page on quadratic integers that is mentioned in the question also uses $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$.  Perhaps the OP made a sign error.

The only time when I'd expect to find anyone singling out $(-1 + \sqrt{D})/2$ as being worthy of having a special label is the case mentioned in Lubin's comment: $D = -3$, since $(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is a nontrivial cube root of unity $\zeta_3$ (while $(1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is a primitive $6$th root of unity $\zeta_6$).  The numbers $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$ and $(-1+\sqrt{D})/2$ differ by $1$, so they generate the same ring over $\mathbf Z$, and it's simply a long-standing tradition when $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ to prefer $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$ as the generator of the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{D})$.

To answer the question that was asked: there is no standard term.  It's just called $\omega$.

Something worth noting is that there is a unified way to write the ring of integers of all quadratic fields without having to make up a notation $\omega$ for $\sqrt{D}$ or $(1+\sqrt{D})/2$ depending on $D \bmod 4$: if the quadratic field $K$ has discriminant $\Delta$, then $\Delta = D$ if $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $\Delta = 4D$ if $D \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and you can check in both cases that
$$
\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z\left[\frac{\Delta + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right] = 
\mathbf Z + \mathbf Z\frac{\Delta + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}.
$$

The first book treatment of "general" algebraic number theory is Supplement XI in Dirichlet-Dedekind's *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie*, where quadratic fields are the topic of Sections 186 and 187 (at least in the 4th edition). The only basis used there for the ring of integers is $\{1,(\Delta + \sqrt{\Delta})/2\}$.  The notation $\omega$ is used there for an algebraic number in $K$, not necessarily an algebraic integer, and the reason for using $\omega$ is that the notation in the book for a general number field is $\Omega$. A number field is called a Schaar = flock/herd -- how picturesque!

Comment: I haven’t worked on this topic for most of the decade since I posted the question, but it’s great to get such a thorough answer!  The background, incidentally, was [implementing Hallgren’s algorithm in Quipper](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/quipper/doc/Quipper-Algorithms-CL-Main.html) — not yet public when I posted. Apologies for misquoting your notes; I’d been sloppy unifying conventions between yours and Josza’s (see the question’s edit history…). But it still seems odd if none of these widely-used choices of generating algebraic integer has a distinctive name!